# How convert PCL generated by HP LaserJet 5 into PDF in C#?

Tags: c#, pdf, printing, printer-control-language

I need to retire 15 years old system and preserve all data. It can only print documents into specific printer HP LaserJet 5. I can print documents into PCL files and looking for ways to convert all this files into PDFs programmatically. Preferably in C#. Can anybody recommend good library or command line tool? Preferably free ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution I found is [VeryPDF PCL Converter](http://www.verypdf.com/pcltools/index.html) http://www.verypdf.com/pcltools/index.html. It has command line mode, GUI (for command line), batch mode and only cost $125. My company has been pay for it. Hope this will help somebody too.

Answer (score 2):

The commandline tool [GhostPCL](http://www.ghostscript.com/GhostPCL/) (part of GhostPDL), by the same developers as Ghostscript, can convert PCL to PDF. Recent changes in their public [source code repository](http://svn.ghostscript.com/) provide a fully integrated source tree encompassing Ghostscript, GhostPCL and GhostXPS. This includes MS Visual Studio *.sln and *.vcproj files to build all or part of their products. License is GPL or commercial (commercial licenses to be obtained from [Artifex](http://www.artifex.com/)):

Answer (score 0):

I've used [Visual Softwares pcl2pdf](http://www.visual.co.uk/) on several projects, it worked well for me.

Comment: It cost $895 compare to $125 for VeryPDF PCL Converter.

Answer (score 0):

We are currently using Lincoln's PCL to PDF converter.  It was simple to call and provides embed into our C# application.  It also provides good feedback in terms of Events when a page has been converted etc so you can even add progress bars etc.

[Lincoln PCL to PDF Converter](http://www.lincolnco.com/products/pclpdfconverter.htm)

Comment: Do you have any examples of how you got it to integrate into your code? I'm trying to get it to work with our system, and unless I put the thread to sleep, it looks like it creates a blank PDF file and closes the app before the conversion finished.

Answer (score 0):

I've used [PCL to PDF for Windows and OS X](http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/pcltopdf.html) which is based on GhostPCL.